# System.Net.Mail.SmtpException - Email Sender

Tags: c#, email

Net.Mail.SmtpException in output when I send any message using Email Sender application made in C#.

**ERROR:** **System.Net.Mail.Smtp.Exception: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at System.Net.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCodestatusCde,Stringresponse)
at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, MailAddressfrom,Boolean allowUnicode) at System.Net.Mail.Smtp.Transport.SendMail(MailAddress sender,MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify,Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at My_first_project.Form1.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\HUSSAM\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C#\Projects\My first project\My first project\Form1.cs:line 80**

Here is the CODE::

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

        try
        {
            if (!textBox4.Text.Contains("@gmail.com"))
            {

                MessageBox.Show("You need to provide @gmail email :)");
                return;

            }

            button2.Enabled = false;
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress(textBox4.Text);
            message.Subject = textBox2.Text;
            message.Body = textBox3.Text;

            foreach (string s in textBox1.Text.Split(';'))
                message.To.Add(s);

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(textBox4.Text, textBox5.Text);
            client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            client.Port = 587;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Send(message);

        }//end try
        catch
        {

            MessageBox.Show("There was error sending the message. Make sure you typed in\r\nyour credentials correctly and that you have an internet connection.", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }
        finally { button2.Enabled = true; }
    }//end button function
```

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: I mentioned above :)

Comment: That's not the actual error message. There's an error message in the exception itself.

Comment: Sorry. I edited the post nw check this error!

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
     var mail = new MailMessage();
     var smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
     mail.From = new MailAddress("email_from");
     mail.To.Add("email_to");
     mail.Subject = "subject";
     mail.Body = "body";
     smtp.Port = 587;
     smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
     smtp.EnableSsl = true;


     smtp.Send(mail);
```

Comment: put catch(Exception e) - and give full exception description